# Ajax functionality are not works in MVC4 webgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ajax paging and sorting is not working in MVC4 WebGrid

here is the code

```
 @{ WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "Grid");
grid.Bind(Model.List, rowCount: Model.TotalRecordCount, autoSortAndPage: false);    }

<div id="grid">
            @grid.Table(
                tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",

                columns: new[] {
                    grid.Column("Id"),
                     grid.Column("SampleText"),
                    grid.Column("Descreption")    
            })
        </div>


@grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
```

I am using jquery-2.1.0.min

Please give me some suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to include jquery before the code to generates grid.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
```